# Which uses more RAM at run time, dynamic linking or static linking?

Tags: c, dynamic, linker, static-linking

I know that dynamic linking are smaller on disk but do they use more RAM at run time. Why if so?

Comment: This is not a general rule. But I would assume it's because it needs to run the dynamic linker in addition to everything.

Comment: Dynamic linking might use less RAM than static linking - by a long way.  Dynamic linking marks the code file (`.dll` or `.so` file) as mapped into *virtual memory*.  Since these will mostly consist of pure read-only code pages then these can be shared between processes using different programs which use those libraries.  Static linking only allows sharing of the same *program* files.

Comment: Dynamically-linked libraries are likely to be *larger* on disk, because the metadata required to support dynamic linking is usually larger than that required to support static linking.  They can reduce overall system RAM usage, however, because only one copy of their code needs to reside in memory, no matter how many processes are using it.

Comment: Static linking could end-up using more disk space depending on how many programs have a copy of each `.dll` or `.so` file embedded in it.  If you have 10 programs using the same library then those 10 will in total use more disk space by static linking because there will be 10 copies of the library.    However, if only one program uses the the library then static linking is probably more efficient.

Comment: From cdarke's and Eugene's comment, we can deduce that it is _less_ RAM if there are two or more processes that use the library, where "or more" means that the overhead of loading the dynamic linker must be subtracted.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is "it depends how you measure it", and also "it depends which platform you're running on".

Static linking uses less runtime RAM, because for dynamic linking the entire shared object needs to be loaded into memory (I'll be qualifying this statement in a second), whilst with static linking only those functions you actually need are loaded.

The above statement isn't 100% accurate. Only the shared object pages that actually contain code you use are loaded. This is still much less efficient than statically linking, which compresses those functions together.

On the other hand, dynamic linking uses much less runtime RAM, as all programs using the same shared object use the same in RAM copy of the code (I'll be qualifying this statement in a second).

The above is a true statement on Unix like systems. On Windows, it is not 100% accurate. On Windows (at least on 32bit Intel, I'm not sure about other platforms), DLLs are not compiled with position independent code. As such, each DLL carries the (virtual memory) load address it needs to be loaded at. If one executable links two DLLs that overlap, the loader will relocate one of the DLLs. This requires patching the actual code of the DLL, which means that this DLL now carries code that is specific to this program's use of it, and cannot be shared. Such collisions, however, should be rare, and are usually avoidable.

To illustrate with an example, statically linking `glibc` will probably cause you to consume more RAM at run time, as this library is, in all likelihood, already loaded in RAM before your program even starts. Statically linking some unique library only your program uses will save run time RAM. The in-between cases are in-between.

Answer (score 2):

Different processes calling the same dll/so file can share the read-only memory pages this includes code or text pages.

However each dll loaded in a given peogram has to have its own page for writable global or static data. These pages may be 4/16/64k or bigger depending on the OS. If one statically linked, the static data can be shared in one pages.

Answer (score 1):

Programs, when running on common operating systems like Linux, Windows, MacOSX, Android, ...., are running as [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) having some [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). This uses [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) (implemented by the [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)) driving the [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)).

Read a good book like [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) to understand more.

So programs don't consume *directly* RAM. The RAM is a resource managed by the kernel. When RAM becomes scarce, your system experiments [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)). Read also about the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) and about [memory overcommitment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment) (a feature that I dislike and that I often disable).

The advantage of using a shared library, when the same library is used by *several* processes, is that its [code segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) is appearing (technically is [paged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging)) only once in RAM.

However, [dynamic linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) has a small overhead (even in memory), e.g. to resolve [relocations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)). So if a library is used by only *one* process, that might consume slightly more RAM than if it was statically linked. In practice you should not bother most of the time, and I recommend using dynamic linking systematically.

And in practice, for huge processes (such as your browser), the data and the heap consumes much more RAM than the code.

On Linux, Drepper's paper [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) explains a lot of things in details.

On Linux, you might use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) to explore virtual address spaces. For example, try `cat /proc/$$/maps` and `cat /proc/self/maps` and `pmap $$` in  a terminal. Use [ldd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) to find out the dynamic libraries dependencies of a program, e.g. `ldd /bin/cat`. Use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to find out what [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) are used by a process. Those relevant to the virtual address space include [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and `munmap`, [mprotect(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html), [mlock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html), the old [sbrk(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html) -obsolete- and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).